# Program crashing when trying to return a boolean

Tags: c++, function, boolean

For this code my goal is to change some functions (more like modularize the program) so that any function that searches the database for a the memberNumber will call an actual search function which returns a boolean value.

Right now I'm already running into a problem with my program crashing whenever the searchID function returns *true*. When it returns false it doesn't crash.

Original working function:

```
bool DonorList::searchID(int memberNumber) const
{
    bool found = false;
    list<DonorType>::const_iterator iter = donors->begin();
    while (iter != donors->end() && !found)
    {
        if (iter->getMembershipNo() == memberNumber)
        {
            found = true;
        }
        else
            ++iter;
    }
    return found;
}
```

Changed function:

```
bool DonorList::searchID(int memberNumber) const
{
    list<DonorType>::const_iterator iter;
    bool found = searchDonorLocation(memberNumber, iter);
    return found;
}
```

Added function:

```
bool DonorList::searchDonorLocation(int memberNumber, list<DonorType>::const_iterator &iter) const
{
    iter = donors->begin();
    bool found = false;
    while (iter != donors->end())
    {
        if (iter->getMembershipNo() == memberNumber)
        {
            found = true;
        }
        else
            iter++;
    }
    return found;
}
```

I have no clue what is causing the issue other than that the program crashes whenever the newly changed function supposedly returns true. I've tried just returning searchDonorLocation(memberNumber, iter) but that causes the exact same crash.

Comment: where is `found` declared? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: My bad, that's a typo on the original function so thanks for pointing that out. It had the bool found = false declared (since if it didn't it definitely wouldn't have worked). Edited post to include it.

Comment: if memberNumber is found. You are not incrementing the iterator,it is going on infinite loop.You should just return true. or break the loop.

Comment: Side note, but I suggest you start preferring prefix `operator++` over postfix. It will save you a bunch of copies you don't need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while (iter != donors->end())
{
    if (iter->getMembershipNo() == memberNumber)
    {
        found = true;
    }
    else
        iter++;
}
```

When they match, your loop never ends because you don't bump your iterator so it can never get to the end. Is it *crashing* or hanging?

In your original code, you test for `!found` which exits the loop.

```
while (iter != donors->end() && !found)
```

Comment: Whoops, you're right! That was a pretty stupid mistake on my part. It works now that I added in the test for found, thanks a bunch!

Comment: some people say to only call return once in a function, but I write this kind of loop with "return true" inside the loop and "return false" after it - and no 'found' variable.   The hurdles people jump through to only have one return statement make the code harder to follow for me.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful that `searchDonorLocation`(..) doesn't exit the while loop if the condition is satisfied.
try:

```
while (iter != donors->end())
{
    if (iter->getMembershipNo() == memberNumber)
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
    else
        iter++;
}
```